# Asp.net i cannot find textboxes in the page

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and asp .net C#. I wrote the code below:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    tbTLCTitle.Text = readMainXml("homepage", "LeftColumnTop", "title");
    String[] liTable = readMainXmlList("homepage", "LeftColumnTop", "textRow");
    for (int i = 0; i < liTable.Length; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.CssClass = "tbCss";
        tb.ID = "textbox" + i;
        tb.Text = liTable[i];
        tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        divTextRow.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("cpTextContent");
    if (cph != null)
    {
        var div = cph.FindControl("divTextRow");
        if (div != null)
        {
            var tb =
                div.FindControl("textbox0");
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.Text = "TextBox found!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am going to explain what I want to do:

I have a div with `id="divTextRow"` and I want to add some textbox objects dynamically.

At `Page_LoadComplete` I read the xml and I create the TextBox objects with text from the xml and `id = "textbox" + i` (example: textbox0).

In my page I have a button with `id="btnSave"` and `OnClick="btnSave_Click"`.

Now I want to take the text from those textbox objects and save it to xml.

I have the code to save to xml but I cannot take the text from textbox objects.

Comment: can you post your html code also?

Comment: can you post the front end code as well?  It would be helpful to see that also.

Comment: Please post the markup for these controls. Are they all server side (`runat="server"`)?

Comment: In your code, you are assigning a value to your textbox. I did not see any code which would get the value from the textbox.

Comment: Are you able to successfully get the div control in `var div = cph.FindControl("divTextRow");`

Comment: Yes I can find the "divTextRow".

Comment: That's the html code
`<div class="content">
    <div id="divTextRow" runat="server">
    </div>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" CssClass="kati"
                Width="220px" BorderStyle="Groove" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Your div tag with `id="divTextRow"` should be a server control in order to do that. Hence add the attribute `runat="server"` to this div tag in the markup of the .aspx file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already done this, so I can find this object (var div = cph.FindControl("divTextRow");). The problem is in that line:
var tb = div.FindControl("textbox0");
I cannot find that object.

Comment: Usually ASP.NET would prefix the IDs of such dynamically generated UI controls based on its scope. hence your textbox might have an ID like "ctl00$cplh$textbox0". I would suggest to do a View Source of the rendered page which has these textboxes and check the IDs of these controls.

Comment: I have tried everything. Asp.net gives them id="cpTextContent_textbox0","cpTextContent_textbox1",etc but I cannot find it..
Maybe the problem is that textboxes on every postback I won't find them because they just don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) article in MSDN. Try using document.getElementById method.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't help me. Maybe because I am not familiar with java.